# Association and model data saving problem

Tags: cakephp, associations, tagging

Developing with cakephp 1.3 (latest from github). 
There are 2 models bind with hasAndBelongsToMany: documents and tags. Document can have many tags in other words. I've add a new document submitting form there user can enter a list of tags separated with commas (new tag will be added, if not exist already). I looked at cakephp bakery 2.0 [source code](http://github.com/cakephp/bakery) on github and found the solution. But it seems that something is wrong.

```
class Document extends AppModel {
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Tag');
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
                if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['tags']) && !empty($this-
>data[$this->alias]['tags']))

                {
                        $tagIds = $this->Tag->saveDocTags($this->data[$this->alias]
['tags']);
                        unset($this->data[$this->alias]['tags']);
                        $this->data[$this->Tag->alias][$this->Tag->alias] = $tagIds;
                }
                return true;
        }

}

class Tag extends AppModel {
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array ('Document');

   public function saveDocTags($commalist = '') {
        if ($commalist == '') return null;
        $tags = explode(',',$commalist);
        if (empty($tags)) return null;
        $existing = $this->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array('title' => $tags)
        ));
        $return = Set::extract($existing,'/Tag/id');
        if (sizeof($existing) == sizeof($tags)) {
            return $return;
        }
        $existing = Set::extract($existing,'/Tag/title');
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            if (!in_array($tag, $existing)) {
                $this->create(array('title' => $tag));
                $this->save();
                $return[] = $this->id;
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }

}
```

So, new tags creation works well but document model can't save association data and tells:
SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
Query: INSERT INTO `documents` (`title`, `content`, `shortnfo`,
`date`, `status`) VALUES ('Document with tags', '', '', Array, 1) 
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

P.S. Post data from firebug for this form:
_method POST
data[Document][content] test document content
data[Document][date][year]  2010
data[Document][shortnfo]    short info about document
data[Document][status]  1
data[Document][tags]    test, categories, list
data[Document][title]   Test title
No arrays as we can see.

Comment: Can you add the data array you are attempting to save?  It looks like $data['Document']['shortnfo'] is an array when it should be an int/string/float/whatever.

Comment: Post request from FireBug:
data[Document][content] = "test document content"
data[Document][date][year]= 2010
data[Document][shortnfo]= "short info about document"
data[Document][status]= 1
data[Document][tags]= "test, categories, list"
data[Document][title]= "Test title"

Answer (score 0):

Solved! :) The problem was in the view:

```
'date'=>array('label'=>'Date', 'type'=>'date', 'dateFormat'=>'Y'),
```

But date field in database. the type of this field is year.